# I got no notification emails (for my tag filters) today.

Tags: bug, email-notification, tag-filters, subscription

More than 24 hours ago I got the last email from my tag filters. I checked some filters and verified that I should have gotten several emails today.

Is there a problem with this feature, currently? If not, is there a way to check if SE tried to send me the emails (and possibly to see bounces/errors, in case there’s a problem with my email server)?

Comment: Same here. I don't get it every day (I have filter for low traffic tag) but I checked now, and the last I got was over two days ago, while there are questions posted both yesterday and today. Looks like a bug on SE side.

Answer (score 2):

Just now I got several (probably all) of the missing notifications at once, from yesterday as well as from today.

Edit: Weren’t all notifications, second batch came in.

Comment: Yeah, whatever was borked got fixed, but one batch at least is lost.